# JPA2:i use a JoinColumn as queryparam to create a query and a exception occurred ,why

Tags: java, jpa, ejb, jpa-2.0

```
    @JoinColumn(name = "want_uid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private BookUsers wantUid;
    @JoinColumn(name = "sale_uid", referencedColumnName = "id")
    @ManyToOne
    private BookUsers saleUid;
    @JoinColumn(name = "book_id", referencedColumnName = "id")
```

this code is from a entity bean 
and i write a query using want_uid as queryparam .as fllows:

```
 BookUsers bookUsers=userDA.findUserByID(wantID);
 Query query= em.createQuery("SELECT b FROM BookOrder b WHERE b.want_uid = :want_uid");
 query.setParameter("want_uid", bookUsers);
```

a exception occurred:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: An exception occurred while creating a query in EntityManager: 
Exception Description: Error compiling the query [SELECT b FROM BookOrder b WHERE b.want_uid = :want_uid], line 1, column 34: unknown state or association field [want_uid] of class [com.xbook.entities.BookOrder].
```

i failed to find the reason...
can you tell me ?
Thanks

Comment: Have you tried with `query.setParameter("want_uid", bookUsers.getId());`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the query

```
b.want_uid
```

needs to be changed to

```
b.wantUid
```

So,

```
SELECT b FROM BookOrder b WHERE b.wantUid = :want_uid
```

Comment: wow...thanks!the problem is so strange...the JoinColumn's name is want_uid ..Why is not this as queryparam?